ROS2 DDS behavior when network is saturated
I've been testing ROS2 Iron DDS behavior over a wifi ad-hoc network in which a publisher publishes data (a Int64MultiArray whose size can be changed) and a subscriber, which is on another machine, receive them and prints the data inter-arrival delay.
Everything works fine until the emitter saturates the bandwidth, that is, it tries to send more data than the amount the network can cope with (wifi data rate was fixed to 6Mbps).
In that case, the subscriber receive a few data at the beginning and then gets stuck. I also verified that wifi frames are correctly received at MAC level.
I tried with different RMW implementations using BEST_EFFORT and RELIABLE QoSProfiles, different depths and so on and the result is the same.
Another thing that surprises me is that the publisher slows down its rate of publication when the subscriber is launched, even in BEST_EFFORT mode (notice that they are in different machines).
All the code was written iusing rclpy.
Does anyone can give me a clue on what could be happening?
Thank you in advance.

In my experience, when you are getting messages initially and then no longer get any successful messages after some time, the problem is the ipv4 frag buffer settings on the receiving end. This particularly affects when communicating large data and would be more significant the larger the data or the faster the data being communicated.
Essentially what happens is that some packets get lost but the successful packets are held in the buffer until the 30 second timeout waiting for the missing packets. This fills up the buffer such that you can no longer ever fully receive a message. I fix this by increasing the buffer size and decreasing the buffer timeout.
This DDS Tuning page talks about how to address it: https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/DDS-tuning.html#cross-vendor-tuning
Their example settings are:
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ipfrag_time=3
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh=134217728     # (128 MB)
I can't speak too much to your later observation without more details (that the publisher changes rates). If you are measuring the rate on a different machine then you will only see what was received which may often be a different rate but that does not mean that the publisher changed rates. If you are measuring it on the same machine then the limiting factor could be just how efficiently your node is able to output the information. In that case there is some other tuning that you can try in terms of the socket read/write buffers, also discussed at that same link. The other possibility I can think of is that if your subscribing node is being launched on a device with multiple different assigned IP addresses (potentially for different nics) then it is possible that the publishing node is trying to send the data in duplicate (or more), once to each IP address that the subscriber can be accessed at which could be contributing to slowing things down.

Unfortunately, it does not solve the issue. However, I believe I found the problem which is probably related to the wifi device driver (ralink cards) since with other (intel cards) it does not happen.
